# Check if path can be resolved using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been wondering how to do this for awhile, without resorting to I/O.
If you look at some well known Node.js libraries, like `nopt` for instance:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nopt

nopt seems to use the core [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module to check whether a path is a actually a resolvable path.

e.g. (forgive their comma first code)

```
  , path = require("path")
  , knownOpts = { "foo" : [String, null]
                , "bar" : [Stream, Number]
                , "baz" : path   //<<<<
```

my guess is that they use the isAbsolute call to make the determination like so:

```
path.isAbsolute(path.resolve(x))
```

and that is what indicates whether a path was resolved or not?

I wonder why they didn't choose to throw an error when a path is not resolved? When calling path.resolve(x), if x is not resolvable, should throw an error instead of just returning the original argument?

Comment: Per the [source code](https://github.com/npm/nopt/blob/master/lib/nopt.js#L134), only `path.resolve(process.env.HOME, val.substr(2))` is invoked? It just parse the option, then the invoked function passed by this option (valid path or invalid path) should handle it, and throw it if invalid in this function. IMO.

Comment: Any string (including empty) can  be resolved and does not cause an error in the `path.resolve`.